# extract headers from uploaded csv file in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to extract the header row of the csv files i upload and display them as checkbox options. Currently, I split based on "\n", then on "," to get the individual column names. However, it does not work for all csv files and some do not get split properly (eg, data cells are returned as column headers). Is there any functions I can use instead? Thanks! My code is shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- jquery -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.7.7/xlsx.core.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xls/0.7.4-a/xls.core.min.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        /*---CSV FUNCTION---*/
        function getColumns_csv() {   
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                var data = e.target.result;
                var header = data.split("\n")[0] //<--- is there a better way to split columns?
                header = header.split(",");

                var cnt = 1;
                $('#columnCheckbox').empty();

                header.forEach(function(y){
                    $('#columnCheckbox').append('<td><input type="checkbox" name='+y+' id="columnSelect'+cnt+'" class="chkbx">'+y+'</td>');
                    cnt++;
                });

                $('.chkbx').on('click',function(){
                    if($('.chkbx:checked').length == $('.chkbx').length){
                        $('#checkall').prop('checked',true);
                    }else{
                        $('#checkall').prop('checked',false);
                    }
                });

                $('.hiddeninputs').show();
                $('#submission').show();
            }
            reader.readAsText($('#datafile')[0].files[0]);
        } 
        /*---//CSV FUNCTION---*/
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //select all button
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#checkall').on('click',function(){
                if(this.checked){
                    $('.chkbx').each(function(){
                        this.checked = true;
                    });
                }else{
                     $('.chkbx').each(function(){
                        this.checked = false;
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Upload File</h3>

        <!-- form to post file -->
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fileform">
            <input type="file" name="datafile" id="datafile">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" name="upload" id="upload" onclick="getColumns_csv()">Upload File</button>
            <br></br>

            <table class="hiddeninputs" hidden="hidden">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="checkall">Select all</td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="columnCheckbox"></tr>
            </table>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="submit" id="submission">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Might try library PapaParse.js. It does some sampling of rows, columns, delimiters etc

Comment: can you post sample data which is not splitting properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
var header = data.split(/[\r\n]+/)[0];
```

If your problem is with line splitting, this will cover more possible `end of line` character.